# Vector space basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If I have no fundamental misunderstanding of vector spaces, my question is as follows.

If an orthogonal basis of a vector space consists of $N$ vectors, is this right that every vector from this basis has $N$ elements (being written as matrix, it is a square matrix $B=\begin{bmatrix} v_{1, 1} & ... & v_{N, 1} \\ ... & ... & ... \\ v_{N, N} & ... & v_{N, N} \end{bmatrix}$)?

From my understanding, the answer is positive. Then I should ask if it could make any sense to have a basis of $N$ vectors each of $M$ elements with $N < M$?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Ok, I'll rephrase. Is the number of vectors and the number of elements in these vectors in every orthogonal basis of a vector space equal? Could an othogonal basis writen in the matrix form have dimension NxM with N <> M?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, it makes no sense. If the dimension of the vector space is $N$, you can write a vector as a linear combination of $M>N$ vectors, but some of these M components are redundant, in the sense that some of the $M$ vectors you use to decompose the original vector are linearly dependent. This means that you can write $M-N$ of these $M$ vectors as a linear combination of the $N$ vectors of any basis, coming back to your starting writing with $N$ "elements". ( if you fix a basis, each vector has a unique representation in term of the vectors of the basis you fixed).

Comment: Great answer, thank you. This way there could be ambigous bases with M>N vectors of N elements, but a set of M<N vectors of N elements could not form any basis of a vector space, right?

Comment: @werediver yes, all basis of a vector space of finite dimension $N$ have the same cardinality $N$. A set of less than $N$ vectors cannot generate the whole vector space. On the other side, if you take a basis and you add some vectors, you get a set of $M>N$ vectors which still generate the space, but you lose the linear indipendence.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your explanations.